# When will they be landing Dragon retropropulsively?

Tags: spacex, landing, dragon

I keep expecting SpaceX to start doing powered landings of the dragon, or at least tests. But to my knowledge they haven't even done a drop test yet. Does anyone know what their plans are in regards to this?

Comment: in July 2017, SpaceX announced they were cancelling the capability to use propulsive landing for Dragon 2 due to issues with getting it certified by NASA. This also meant canceling Red Dragon. https://spaceflightnow.com/2017/07/19/propulsive-landings-nixed-from-spacexs-dragon-spaceship/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SpaceX had a permit/environmental assessment for their Dragonfly test vehicle/series of tests. It included the full gamut of ground level tests (at least one completed, hover test on a crane ([video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=07Pm8ZY0XJI)) and then helicopter drops, propulsive landings, and then boosted hops.

They have been very quiet about performing these tests for some reason.

Of course, the initial Dragon V2 build (apparently based on a Cargo Dragon hull but with Super Dracos added) was tested with the [pad abort from LC-40](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1_FXVjf46T8) on May 6, 2015. They have since indicated that the Dragon V2 design changed sufficiently that they do not want to test further with that initial design. Instead, the first unmanned Dragon V2 will do a pad abort as its second mission.
The initial plan is to parachute into the ocean for the first set of manned flights and then later land propulsively.

Comment: The [pad abort test](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1_FXVjf46T8) might also be worth a mention.

Comment: To make sure I'm understanding, *the permit* included all those things you mention, correct?  There is no evidence that any of them have actually taken place?